# Excel count number of occurrences of multiple values in multiple set of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using Windows OS and Office 2016 Desktop version. In Excel file, I have following data set pattern:

[image: Original data on which have to perform calculation]

There are a large number of samples and for each sample I have multiple variables named as As, Bs, Cs and Ds etc.
I want to count number of occurrences of each variable against each sample in the form of image below which shows count of the each specific variable's presence inside the data set :

[image]

I can achieve the above mentioned result by using count formula for a single sample, but unable to find a way to do it for a large number of samples (around 1 lac) where each sample contains more than 600 variables.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: PivotTable and add to data model, do you try this method? Not sure what's the data source you're using, you can check if this method is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` function as shown below:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$22,"="&$D4,$B$2:$B$22,"="&E$3)
```

Drag to fill the other cells. Change ranges to adapt to your data.

[image]

Comment: Problem solved by your solution. Deleted all irrelevant comments that were cause of discussion due to mistake in typing.

Comment: The solution works very well for small number of samples but Microsoft Excel crashes when there are large number of samples and data. I have around 4000 variables and more than 150,000 samples. Adding formula to range of cells takes around 5,6 hours and excel crashes. Any optimal solution to deal with this problem?

Comment: Never mind. I used pivot tables and it literally took few seconds to calculate as compared to formula which took around 3 hours and took extensive system resources with Intel Core i7 and 16Gb of RAM.